# Assigning Random Variables

Tags: probability, random-variable

(Sum of die rolls). We roll two fair 6-sided dice. Let T = X + Y be the total of the two rolls, where X and Y are the individual rolls. The sample space of this experiment has 36 equally likely outcomes:
S = {(1,1),(1,2),...,(6,5),(6,6)}.

For example, 7 of the 36 outcomes s are shown in the table below, along with the corresponding values of X,Y, and T.
[image]

After the experiment is performed, we observe values for X and Y , and then the observed value of T is the sum of those values.

Since the dice are fair, the PMF(Probability Mass Function) of X is
P(X = j) = 1/6,
for j = 1,2,...,6 (and P(X = j) = 0 otherwise); we say that X has a Discrete Uniform distribution on 1, 2, . . . , 6. Similarly, Y is also Discrete Uniform on 1, 2, . . . , 6.
Note that Y has the same distribution as X but is not the same random variable as X. In fact, we have
P(X =Y)=6/36=1/6.
Two more r.v.s in this experiment with the same distribution as X are 7 − X and 7−Y . To see this, we can use the fact that for a standard die, 7−X is the value on the bottom if X is the value on the top. If the top value is equally likely to be any of the numbers 1, 2, . . . , 6, then so is the bottom value. Note that even though 7−X has the same distribution as X, it is never equal to X in a run of the experiment!
Let’s now find the PMF of T . By the naive definition of probability,

```
***> P(T =2)=P(T =12)=1/36  P(T =3)=P(T =11)=2/36 P(T =4)=P(T =10)=3/36 
> P(T =5)=P(T =9)=4/36  P(T =6)=P(T =8)=5/36  P(T = 7) = 6/36.***
```

For all other values of t, P(T = t) = 0. We can see directly that the support of T
98 Introduction to Probability is {2, 3, . . . , 12} just by looking at the possible totals for two dice, but as a check,
note that
P(T =2)+P(T =3)+···+P(T =12)=1,
which shows that all possibilities have been accounted for. The symmetry property of T that appears above, P(T = t) = P(T = 14−t), makes sense since each outcome {X = x,Y = y} which makes T = t has a corresponding outcome {X = 7−x,Y = 7 − y} of the same probability which makes T = 14 − t.

***so this is the problem, however I understand that P(X=j) that j is some event in the sample space, but the question is what P(X=Y) means? we assign the random variable X to some event j but When P(X=Y) we assign the random variable X to the random Variable Y, I need some explanation here?***

Comment: I'd try: $P(X=k \text{ and } Y=k)$ :) BTW, we do not assign anything. $P(X=j)$ just means: probability that $X$ is equal to $j$.

Comment: Since you have discrete distributions, you can say $P(X=Y) = \sum\limits_k P(X=k \text{ and } Y=k)$.  If $X$ and $Y$ are independent you would then be able to say $P(X=Y) = \sum\limits_k P(X=k)\, P(Y=k)$

Comment: Ok, I see now, so P(X=Y) = 6/36 in the question means the some event k will be X=k and Y=k, in other words, in the question it stated that X is the first dice and  Y is the second dice, that means there are 6 possibilities out of 36 when X=Y and these possibilities are{(1,1), (2,2),....,(6,6)} so the k will range from 1 to 6.